# Tweak code to expand web parts in Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint

I'm trying to tweak some code I found online to create an expand button beside a web part in a Sharepoint site. The issue with this code is that the default is that all web parts are already expanded, and you would have to click to collapse it.  I would only like to have my FAQ (WebPartWPQ7) web part already collapsed, and users can expand it with a click.  The other web parts do not need an expand/collapse button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//
// Expand/Collapse Buttons
//

function WPToggle(thisId, ImageId) {
    if (document.getElementById(thisId).style.display == "none") {
        document.getElementById(thisId).style.display = "";
        document.getElementById(ImageId).src = "/_layouts/images/minus.gif";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(thisId).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(ImageId).src = "/_layouts/images/plus.gif";
    }
}

function ExpandCollapseBody() {
    var i = 1;
    var WPid = "WebPartWPQ1";
    var WPtitleid = "WebPartTitleWPQ1";
    var Toggleid = "ToggleImage1";
    do {
        try {
            document.getElementById(WPtitleid).innerHTML = '<IMG id="' + Toggleid + '" onClick="WPToggle(\'' + WPid + '\',\'' + Toggleid + '\')" alt="Expand/Collapse" style="margin:6px 5px 0px 2px; float:left; cursor:pointer;" src="/_layouts/images/minus.gif" />' + document.getElementById(WPtitleid).innerHTML;
            if (document.getElementById(WPid).style.display == "none") {
                document.getElementById(Toggleid).src = "/_layouts/images/plus.gif";
            }
        } catch (err) {}
        i = i + 1;
        WPid = "WebPartWPQ" + i;
        WPtitleid = "WebPartTitleWPQ" + i;
        Toggleid = "ToggleImage" + i;
    } while (document.getElementById(WPid))
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("ExpandCollapseBody()");
</script>
```

Comment: Add a `style="display: none;"` attribute to your HTML element with `id="WebPartWPQ1"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to hide the 7th web part, just add a `if (i == 7) WPToggle(WPid, ToggleId);` to the initialization function. Slightly adapted your code with jquery as you tagged your question as such I assume you can use it:

```
function WPToggle(thisId, ImageId) {
    var isVisible = $('#' + thisId).is(':visible');
    $('#' + thisId).toggle(!isVisible);

    var img = isVisible ?  'plus' : 'minus';
    $('#' + ImageId).attr('src', '/_layouts/images/' + img + '.gif');
}

function ExpandCollapseBody() {
    var i = 1;
    do {
        var WPid = 'WebPartWPQ' + i;
        var WPtitleid = 'WebPartTitleWPQ' + i;
        var Toggleid = 'ToggleImage' + i;
        var htmlImg = '<img id="' + Toggleid + '" alt="Expand/Collapse" style="margin:6px 5px 0px 2px; float:left; cursor:pointer;" src="/_layouts/images/minus.gif" />';
        var wpTitle = $('#' + WPtitleid).data('idx', i);
        wpTitle
            .html(htmlImg + wpTitle.html())
            .click(function() {
                var idx = $(this).data('idx');
                WPToggle('WebPartWPQ' + idx, 'ToggleImage' + idx);
            });
            if (i == 7) WPToggle(WPid, Toggleid);
        i++;
    } while ($('#WebPartWPQ' + i).length == 1)
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("ExpandCollapseBody()");
```

Comment: Hi Steve!  Thank you so much for your help.  The FAQ is functioning properly, but all of the other web parts have a collapse button beside them.  How can I remove that?

Comment: Ok, you can remove then the do-while loop and change the first line of the function to  `var i = 7;`. This applies the code only to the 7th webpart.

Comment: I took out the do-while loop and changed var i = 7 in the ExpandCollapseBody function, and now no buttons are showing.  I'll continue tweaking.

Comment: Just to make sure, do not remove the contents of the do-while loop, just the 2 lines containing `do {` and `} while ($('#WebPartWPQ' + i).length == 1)`